# retweeting using twitteR

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-r

Is it possible to retweet a status using the twitteR package (or just R in general)?

For example, if I import a bunch of tweets and I want to retweet one of them:

```
library(twitteR)

# load ROAuth handshake (authorization to interact with Twitter) and check if connection to twitter is established
load(file = "twitteR_credentials")
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)

# search Twitter for 25 tweets containing the term '#twitter' and take the first one
tweets = searchTwitter('#twitter', n=25)
favorite_tweet = tweets[1]

# is there a function that lets me retweet favorite_tweet to my own timeline?
```

I know you can use the `updateStatus` function to post a status consisting of text, but is there a similar function which lets you update your status by retweeting another status?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this exact same problem trying to make a retweet bot. Python's `tweepy` and `twython` don't seem to be playing nice lately, but R is connecting fine to twitter's API. I can `updateStatus("hello world!")` alright, but when I try to do something like `updateStatus(favorite_tweet)` as in your example, I get this error:

```
[1] "Authorization Required"
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall("statuses/update", params = params,  : 
  Error: Authorization Required
```

Obviously since in the same session I am able to `updateStatus("hello world!")` something is up. They have my authorization, and it's working just fine.

The best I can figure out is that `favorite_tweet` is [an object of class status](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf). This seems to be preventing `updateStatus()` from interpreting it as a string that can be retweeted. I tried `unlist()` and manipulating it with `gsub()` but haven't found a good solution yet. If I do, I'll let you know (and I hope if you do, you'll let me know).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
updateStatus(favorite_tweet[[1]]$text)
```

Note that your favorite_tweet is still a list, so it might be slightly better to rather do:

```
favorite_tweet = tweets[[1]]
updateStatus(favorite_tweet$text)
```

which gets rid of extraneous indexing.

The key though is that you are wanting to retweet the text content of the tweet, not the tweet object itself.